# split application on two server

Tags: php, split, server, scalability

I have a PHP shop-application (session-based) on `myserver1.com`. I want to outsource one module which is very performance-hungry into another server `myserver2.com`.

I thought I could redirect the user by clicking on a button to the module on
`myserver2.com`.
The session would be stored with a token and if the user came back from `myserver2.com`, I would start the "saved" session again.

Is here another easy possibility to get the two apps on two different server together ?

Comment: I would keep the user on one server and have the server itself offload specific tasks to the other server in the background. None of the user's business what happens where...

Comment: There can be more problems caused by this method. e.g Database conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By my knowledge as you don't want to engage server architecture, The easiest/cheapest way for you is to use a cloud hosting so you can control how much of the processor power you need.

Read more about it on [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing).

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a single app in to two servers will have further issues with session cookies and urls, since i guess you're using a application package. If the sub module is not portable and cannot be transfered to another server as you suggest this might help:

what you can do is route through a **Load Balancer**, take a look at [DNS round robbing load balancers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-dns-round-robin-load-balancing-for-high-availability), how to set them up. This way the parent server(load balancer) will route the incoming load to a child server through a proxy thus splitting the server load.

Further more you may [**replicate** the database](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql) so the load on the master database can be lowered.

If it's a shop site i think most of your product pages will be static, (not updated frequently) so it's a good idea to cache those pages from the http side. I recommend using [**Vanish**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-varnish-with-apache-on-ubuntu-12-04--3) for this. It caches selected pages so once a page is cached it will return the cached page without even hitting the application or the database.

Comment: "i have two single managed servers(1 and 1) and i cant install software on the servers, because they are managed by the provider/hoster.
so i cant use loadbalancer or Master/Slave Combis.

my app is selfmade - no framework or package." By @user1121575